# Cannot send e-mail because I get a message that the certificate has expired

Tags: email

I'm trying to send an e-mail on my I-Mac and I get the message that the certificate has expired for smpt.mail.yahoo.com.  I have already checked that the system clock is correct.

Comment: What is the validity date on the certificate?

Comment: who's actually your provider…. mine has recently dumped Yahoo as their underlying mail server.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like they just rotated their certificate.

```
Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
    Issuer: C=US, O=Symantec Corporation, OU=Symantec Trust Network, CN=Symantec Class 3 Secure Server CA - G4
    Validity
        Not Before: Jun 23 00:00:00 2015 GMT
        Not After : Jun 22 23:59:59 2016 GMT
    Subject: C=US, ST=California, L=Sunnyvale, O=Yahoo Inc., OU=Information Technology, CN=smtp.mail.yahoo.com
```